# Redirect to view / Refresh view after generated files are downloaded asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, zip, refresh, download

I have a list view and I want to export all the data as txt files. As the requirement I need to create 3 txt files by clicking Export button. I have a controller action to generate those files and download them as a zip file. When I click the Export button it will trigger the action "ExportFiles". And at same time I want to redirect to the action "List" as i want to refresh the view.

But problem is I cannot do both task at same time. So how can i do it?

This is my code;

```
    public virtual ActionResult List()
    {
        // Code : showing my list
        return view();
    }

    public virtual ActionResult ExportFiles()
    {
        // Code : Generating files
        return new ZipResult(filePath, fileName + ".zip");
        // HERE I WANT TO REFRESH MY VIEW
    }

    public class ZipResult : ActionResult
    {
        private readonly string _filePath;
        public string Filename { get; set; }

        public ZipResult(string filePath, string fileName)
        {
            _filePath = filePath;
            Filename = fileName;
        }

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            if (context == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("context");
            }

            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
            response.ContentType = "application/gzip";
            using (var zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                zip.AddFile(_filePath);
                zip.Save(response.OutputStream);
                var cd = new ContentDisposition
                {
                    FileName = Filename,
                    Inline = false
                };
                response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather it is impossible to do both refresh and file download on one response.
When you try, you will get exception like "Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent".

You would have to tweak your strategy a little bit, f.e.:

- Refresh page manually after certain timeout by JS/jQuery after the Export button is clicked.
- Return page with additional meta-refresh tag, which will redirect to the download url:
  `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5,url=DownloadFile.aspx" />`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since your export will return a file, it sounds like you simply need to refresh the view that you're starting from (your list). If that is the case, then what I do is have the page refresh a few seconds after a download button is selected (i do this so the view will show updated download counts and date).

In the View (your list) I typically add an onclick event to the download button(s) that run a script similar to below. Everything else stays the same.

```
function ReloadPage()
{
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.reload(1);
    }, 5000);
}
```